# show 2 array through ng-repeat error

Tags: arrays, angularjs

i am trying to make a table from 2 arrays in `AngularJS` one array contains Employees name and other array contain Services Name and rest of the cells contain check boxes but when i do i got error `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`

here is my AngularJS code

```
     var model = angular.module('wizard', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/m5", {
            controller: "model5Controller",
            templateUrl: "/templates/m5.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);

    var model5Controller = ["$scope", "$http", "$window", function ($scope,
 $http, $window) {
    $scope.PBA = [];
    $scope.SOB = [];

    $http.get('/Test/GetPBA').
        then(
        function (result) {
            //success
            $scope.PBA = result.data;
        },
        function () {
            //error
        });

    $http.get('/Test/GetSOB').
        then(
        function (result) {
            //success
            $scope.SOB = result.data;
        },
        function () {


    //error
    });

    $scope.save = function () {
//to be written
    };
    }];
```

**GetPBA/GetSOB returns `JSON` type `Array of List`
both contain properties like Id, Name**

here is my html

```
<div>
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Services</strong></td>
            <td ng-repeat="e in PBA">{{e.Name}}</td>
        </td>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in SOB">
            <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="e in PBA">
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{e.Id}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in SOB track by $index">
      <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="e in PBA track by $index">
          <input type="checkbox" name="{{e.Id}}" />
      </td>
</tr>
```